# How to declare of array of pointers to 2D arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have a list of 2D arrays:

```
float a[][9] = { ... }
float b[][9] = { ... }
float c[][9] = { ... }
```

I want to have another array of pointers that point to each of the 2D arrays, like this:

```
what_should_be_here?? arr[] = { a, b, c }
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: I would rework the design. Otherwise I would write something and see what the compiler says it expects

Comment: @KarthikT so what's the better design?

Comment: It depends on the situation. Typically I find that most multidimentional arrays can be more cleanly translated to 1D struct arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `typedef` to simplify  declaration. Each of the element of arr is `float (*)[9]`. Say this type is `SomeType`. Then `{a,b,c}` means you need an array of three elements of type `SomeType`.

```
SomeType arr[] = {a,b,c};
```

Now the question is, **what** is `SomeType`? So here you go:

```
typedef float (*SomeType)[9]; //SomeType is a typedef of `float (*)[9]`

SomeType arr[] = {a,b,c}; //this will compile fine now!
```

As I said, **use `typedef` to simplify declaration!**

I would choose a better name for `SomeType`:

```
typedef float (*PointerToArrayOf9Float)[9];

PointerToArrayOf9Float arr[] = {a,b,c};
```

That is a longer name, but then it makes the code readable!

Note that without typedef, your code will look like this:

```
float (*arr[])[9] = {a,b,c};
```

which is UGLY. That is why I will repeat:

#### Use `typedef` to simplify declaration!

Hope that helps.